# Android query SQLIte syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I receive data from an Activity in which I create a SQL query, but I'm getting syntax error in string. Thanks for help

```
String sql = "SELECT _Id,Date,cas,N,E,Altro FROM Ge WHERE Ea>0 AND cas LIKE "+c_ricevuta+" AND date LIKE '"+anno_ricevuto+"-%' ORDER BY data DESC";
```

here syntax error: `cas LIKE "+c_ricevuta+"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c_ricevuta` should likely be in single quotes `''`:

```
String sql = "SELECT _Id,Date,cas,N,E,Altro FROM Ge WHERE Ea>0 AND cas LIKE '"+c_ricevuta+"' AND date LIKE '"+anno_ricevuto+"-%' ORDER BY data DESC";
```

Note that using string params in your query like this is prone to both syntax errors and SQL injection. Have a look at `?` literal placeholders instead, e.g. the selectionArgs in [query functions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 0):

just in case, I'd place spaces between the word and the "+". Plus, you're not using quotes to surround c_ricevuta

Comment: `I'd place spaces between the word and the "+".` what for?

Comment: I've seen some errors pop up because of details like that. Plus it's a good practice to make your code more readable

Comment: it's a good practice, yes (but the line's length does come first to mind when looking at this code in terms of readability), but it does not cause error. never.